# Magneto admin Url is not working . Need to clear cache always

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cache, admin-panel, file-permissions

I am using magneto 2.2.6 . The website is working fine until i installed new extension .
 When the time of installation i run the following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

When i installed new extension i can't access the admin panel . so i google it and find one solution . https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-backend-is-not-working.html

After doing this the admin panel is working . But now the problem is after logout then again admin panel is not working . I have to clear cache using ssh always `php bin/magento cache:clean` .

How to solve this .

The current situation is for to login admin panel i have to do `php bin/magento cache:clean` always .
Also i can't update the product details . Fr to update product details also i have to clear cache always . Please help

Comment: You may try once by setting up https domain url for both secure and unsecure urls. I have similar kind of issue recently in one of my projects and I got it resolved using this solution.

Comment: sorry , i don't understand . I have https url

Comment: this issue is coming only after i installed new extension

Comment: Ok, this was my assumption. Your case might be different. I just let you know if it might help you. If I know any other thing then I will let you know.

Comment: thank you very much